# How to run the powershell scripts located in Public Git folder without downloading to local drive

Tags: powershell

I have few Power shell scripts saved in my public Git folder. I am not finding a way to run them directly without downloading to my local drive. is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://github.com/yourrepo/yourscript.ps1") | iex
```

This technically downloads it, but then sends the result directly to `invoke-expression` for execution, so I don’t think the script ends up permanently downloaded. This is the method you most typically see for this.

Comment: Right - by using this technique, the script never touches the disk. Just make sure you know what you're downloading :-) (The fact that the script is never on disk made this technique a favourite among malware authors. This is largely mitigated in V5 with [ScriptBlock Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.0/audit_script))

Comment: In PowerShell v3+ you can also use `Invoke-RestMethod` which is a bit cleaner than creating the web client object.

Comment: When I tried above suggested option ((new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://github.com/yourrepo/yourscript.ps1") | iex ) I am getting exception.

Comment: Exception Details :Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
At line:1 char:1
+ (new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://github.com/Gowtham ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Comment: Adding [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 to my script has solved the issue.
Finally it worked as shown below
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("<<Your Git URI>>")